# Unable to launch the Java application Strados2

Tags: java

I am running a Toshiba Windows 8.1 and I have Java Version 8 Update 25 and I’m trying to open Strados2, [a program on a game website found here](http://www.gravon.de/gravon/stratego/strados2.jsp).

However, when I try to run Strados2 it says

> Unable to launch the application.

And when I hit `details` it says:

```
Found unsigned entry in resource:
http://www.gravon.de.webstart/strados2/commons/-discovery.jar
```

I tried going into Configure Java and deleting the cache [like it is recommended to do here](http://compinfopro.com/unable-to-launch-the-application-java-error/), but that didn’t fix it.

I also have tried running Strados2 on an iMac, but that didn’t work either. I also know that others have tried running this program to no avail, but I think it’s supposed to work.

Comment: Try to downgrade Java to version 7 Update 40 or below.

Comment: Just uninstalled Java 8 and installed version 7 Update 40 and still same error :/

Comment: I also tried putting the security down to the minimum (which was medium level)

Comment: The post by the user 'stratego' in 2012 found here :http://www.gravon.de/phpBB/viewtopic.php?t=836 seems to indicate this problem may be unsolvable. If it just can't work I'll give the bounty to whoever can provide the most detailed answer as to why it won't work.

Comment: Try a version below 40, as there were many changes in that version.

Comment: Java version 7 update 1 wasn't able to get it working :/

Comment: I was actually able to contact the site administrator about the issue, and he said he would email me once the problem is fixed, as for the bounty I'll award Jake since he is the only one who posted an answer. Thx harrymc for your help.

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440841/jre-1-7u45-unable-to-load-an-applet-containing-some-unsigned-entries/20469935#20469935) as well as [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923635/found-unsigned-entry-in-resource/23874664#23874664) on Stack Overflow seems to indicate the “Found unsigned entry in resource:” is somehow connected to the “Temporary Files Settings” in Java.

They both state you should go to the control panel for Java, then go to “Temporary Files Settings” and either activate or deactivate the setting “Keep temporary files on my computer.”

Comment: Just tried it and tried deleting the cache as well and it still has the same error...